# pass the input value if checkbox is checked, values are in array?

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<?php include("database/connect.php"); ?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <?php
        $q = mysqli_query($con,"select * from tbl_user");
        while($f=mysqli_fetch_array($q))
        {
            ?>
            <input type="checkbox" name="ch[]" value="<?php echo $f['id'];?>"/>
            <input type="number" name="qty[]"/><br>
            <?php
        }
    ?>

    <input type="submit" name="yy" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

From above code I want the value of the qty if the check box is checked.
I tried like `array_combine` and `foreach` if any one know logic then comment.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to set the index in `qty[]` (`"qty[" + index + "]"`)

Comment: thanks for your reply, can I know any simple example

Comment: check Ankit's answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A number input (unless it is disabled or lacks a name) will always be successful and appear in the data.

A checkbox will only be successful if it is checked.

This means that using PHP's simple array syntax will cause your inputs to get out of sync with each other. The first number input will have the same index as the first **checked** checkbox, and so on.

To deal with this: Give the inputs **explicit** indexes.

For example:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="ch[]" value="<?php echo $f['id'];?>"/>
<input type="number" name="qty[<?php echo $f['id'];?>]"/><br>
```

Then in the PHP you can:

```
foreach ($_POST[ch] as $ch_value) {
    do_something_with($_POST['qty'][$ch_value]);
}
```

Comment: This is easy with php thanks, it's also working fine

Answer (score 0):

You can associate a `onclick` handler in that checkbox and make the `onclick` function to provide you with the value of `qty[]` only when it is checked. For that send the reference to the element and the index to the `onclick` function and use the same index to name the elements `ch` and `qty`:

```js
function cbClick(e, index) {
  if (e.checked) {
    var qty = document.querySelector('input[name="qty['+index+']"]').value;
    console.log('cb value '+ e.value);
    console.log('qty value' + qty);
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- You will loop the PHP code to give the name to each elements with 0, 1, 2..-->
<input type="checkbox" name="ch[0]" onclick="cbClick(this, 0)" value="cb9" />
<input type="number" name="qty[0]" /><br>

<input type="checkbox" name="ch[1]" onclick="cbClick(this, 1)" value="cb10" />
<input type="number" name="qty[1]" /><br>
```

Comment: thanks, but what about check box value??it will also change right, i required both check box value as well as input value if the check box is checked?